# Include no database selected

Tags: php, include, connection, xampp, dreamweaver

I have a project (exisiting) and I am ordered to continue it

but there's something strange

in my connection

```
<?php 

include "adodb5/adodb.inc.php";
$config['mysqlhost'] = 'localhost';
$config['mysqluser'] = 'xxx';
$config['mysqlpass'] = 'yyy';
$config['mysqldb'] = 'zzz';

$DB = ADONewConnection('mysql');
$DB->Connect($config['mysqlhost'],$config['mysqluser'],$config['mysqlpass'],$config['mysqldb'],true);

?>
```

and if I try to call query (same queries as below) from this page, it works (and when I echo, it shows the value)

So I go to other page

```
<?
    include ("inc/con.php");
?>

<?php 

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM table");
$query = mysql_query($sql)or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $result ['table id'];

?>
```

and the result is

> Notice: Undefined variable: myQuery in C:\xampp\htdocs\d88\www\mypage.php on line 9

No database selected

is there anything wrong with it?
since i try on con page, it works and when i include it to other page, it not working

Comment: why dont just wrap the code with one open and one close tag(in second page)? what php version that you are using?

Comment: Should you run your query on $DB?

Comment: Why are using ADODb? PHP has core functionality for this like PDO or mysqli. $myQuery is not set anywhere, therefore undefined. No database is selected because you haven't set up mysql() but only created a ADODB-connection-object.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining any `$myQuery` either in `inc/con.php` nor in the same file itself. Also you are not selecting any database with [`mysql_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php):

```
mysql_select_db($config['mysqldb']);
```

You are suggest, also, not to use `mysql_*` functions as they are going to be deleted and are yet deprecated (and you can use PDO or mysqli).

*Notice: I think `$sql = ("SELECT * FROM table")` gets evaluated as `$sql = true`*.

Comment: `$myQuery` should probably be `$sql`.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, if i use $query = mysql_query($sql)or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); the result is SELECT * FROM table

No database selected, why its no database selected

Comment: @deniaugtaviano, because, as I said in the answer you have to select a database with `mysql_select_db`.

Comment: hi, sorry again for asking, the other php files in my project cannot showing too, but i'm sure they should be working, because it was pulled from the server directly, what should i do now :(

Comment: @deniaugtaviano, have you tried adding (before the `mysql_query` call) the line I posted in my answer?

Comment: $sql = ("SELECT * FROM table"); 

mysql_select_db($config['zzz']) // example my db name is zzz ( am i correct like this ? )

$query = mysql_query($sql)or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); 

$result = mysql_fetch_array($query); 

echo $result ['table_id']; 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\d88\www\mypage.php on line 13

Comment: i might be found out, i must use <?php instead of <? 
thanks for all that helped me

Comment: @deniaugtaviano, you have missed a `;` at the end of `mysql_select_db(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not connect with ADODB connection and establish a query with `mysql_query`.
the syntax is something like this `mysql_query ($query ,$con)`. `$con` is optional but if you do not specify it, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed; but you have not any `mysql_connect()` statement before

Answer (score 0):

because of my version of php, i must use `<?php ?>` instead of `<? ?>`
thanks for helping